# Where could I find PHP 5.3.1 x64 binaries (for IIS 7.5)?

Tags: php, 64-bit, iis-7.5

I'm installing a new server with Windows 2008 R2 and now I need to install PHP on it.

I can find only x86 versions into http://windows.php.net/download/

I don't know how to compile the sources nor I have the VC compilers :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 binaries should run fine even on Windows x64. Have you tried the x86 ones and found them to not work?

Comment: Thanks. It never happened to me... :)